# Get location on Android

Tags: android, geolocation

I am running this piece of code, but cannot see anything significant on logcat.

What I am missing?

Here is the my activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  LocationListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

       GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

       LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        Button btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);


        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //SERVICE STARTED HERE
//                 Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainService.class);
//                 getBaseContext().startService(i);  
                   Log.d("SERVİCE", "START");
                   mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                   Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "SERVICE START", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //SERVICE STOP HERE
                 Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainService.class);
                 getBaseContext().stopService(i); 
                   Log.d("SERVİCE", "STOP");
                   mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "SERVICE STOP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }
//  @Override
//  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      Log.d("KORDINAT-lat", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
//      Log.d("KORDINAT-long", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
//  }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("TAG", "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(2000); // Update location every second

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
//          
//       Location location=   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
//       Log.d("KORDINAT-lat", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
//       Log.d("KORDINAT-long", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.d("TAG", "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Location received: " , location.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }
```

I also add the required permession on Android files like the below:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Also added the `meta-data` but nothing seems to happen nothing. Logcat shows me no error.

Comment: try to set fastest interval (setFastestInterval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you expecting to be output? If the client connects successfully it simply requests location updates. If the location doesn't change it will not output anything.

Comment: emmm yes good point ,but how get the current location though

Comment: LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient) might be of some help

Comment: Call that in onConnected(), it might be null but it shouldn't be

Comment: I did,but as u said getting null exception with the this output 03-06 16:12:04.850: E/AndroidRuntime(30961):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.jm.f(Unknown Source)

Comment: Are you using an actual device or the emulator?

Comment: actual device I am using

Comment: Trying opening google maps or something similar that uses the location services, check if that triggers any output

Comment: Thank you so much,seems  location services on my phone was closed.I open it and it works fine

Comment: No worries :) glad we got it sorted